# Ways to improve XML merging process time

Tags: c#, xml, merge

So i have this code:

```
        foreach (string xmlfilelisted in xmlFileList)
        {
            resultXml.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(xmlfilelisted).Root.Elements());
            resultXml.Save(filepath);
        }
```

This is basically to merge a large number of same format xml files. Now this processes about 1300 files in a minute and half. I want to process, say 200k files. How do i go about that? Clearly the above code wont be practical to do it.

Any links or snippets would be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not enough an IO expert to help speed this up, but I know that ever IO operation is going to slow things down, and you are doing it twice per loop.  Moving the `Save` method call outside the loop and only do it once will save you some time

Comment: Damn, that would be it! I'm going to chalk that down as yet another blonde moment for me. Thanks!

Comment: if that's enough answer for you, I'm going to put my comment as an answer

Comment: It seems like the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your `Save()` method call outside the loop.  You just have to worried about exceptions throwing away all of the results so maybe you can put the `Save()` inside of a `finally` block.

```
try
{
    foreach (string xmlfilelisted in xmlFileList)
    {
        resultXml.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(xmlfilelisted).Root.Elements());
    }
}
finally
{
    resultXml.Save(filepath);
}
```

Comment: Would there be any way of further speeding up things?

Comment: @ShoaibMohamed since you are reading a file each time through the loop, the bottleneck is probably the IO operation and that is limited based the the speed of your hard drive (or Network connection if you are downloading the file).  It is not practical given the number of files, but the only way I can think of to speed up the loop is to read everything into memory first then merge, but that is not really going to save you time as you still have to read the file.

Comment: I agree, its probably not going to make a significant difference.

Comment: I'm getting out of my element, but maybe you can break your `xmlFileList` collection into groups, then read the files in a background thread while you merge the previous set.  You merge is likely going to be much faster, so you'll have to pause between merge operations, but since you are reading and merging at the same time, it should go faster.